# Program loops at id number call as well as not entering information into array

Tags: c, arrays, printf

So my program is trying to take in some information from a user and add them to an array of structs. If you could help I would appreciate it. The program keeps looping at the "Please enter a valid ID number:" and I don't know why. Also when using a print function later on in main, non of the user's information is being added to the array.

```
void add_employee(Employee *db, int db_size){
    int tst1, tst2, tst3, tst4 = 0;
    char temp_first[MAXNAME];
    char temp_last[MAXNAME];
    int temp_six_digit_id;
    int temp_salary;
    db_size++;
    printf("Please enter a first name:\n");
    if(scanf("%s", temp_first) == 1){tst1 == 1;}
    else{
            printf("Please enter a valid name.\n");
            while(tst1 == 0){
                    if(scanf("%s", temp_first) == 1){tst1 == 1;}
                    else{printf("Please enter a valid name.\n");}
                    }
    }
    printf("Please enter a last name:\n");
    if(scanf("%s", temp_last) == 1){tst2 == 1;}
    else{
            printf("Please enter a valid name.\n");
            while(tst2 == 0){
                    if(scanf("%s", temp_last) == 1){tst2 == 1;}
                    else{printf("Please enter a valid name.\n");}
                    }
    }
    printf("Please enter the six digit ID number:\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &temp_six_digit_id) == 1){tst3 ==1;}
    else{
            printf("Please enter a valid ID number:\n");
            while(tst3 == 0){
                    if(scanf("%d", &temp_six_digit_id) == 1){tst3 == 1;}
                    else{printf("Please enter a valid ID number:\n");}
                    }
    }
    printf("Please enter the salary:\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &temp_salary) ==1){tst4 == 1;}
    else{
            printf("Please enter a valid Salary:\n");
            while(tst3 == 0){
                    if(scanf("%d", &temp_salary) == 1){tst3 == 1;}
                    else{printf("Please enter a valid Salary:\n");}
            }
    }
    strcpy(db[db_size].first_name, temp_first);
    strcpy(db[db_size].last_name, temp_last);
    db[db_size].six_digit_id = temp_six_digit_id;
    db[db_size].salary = temp_salary;
```

}

Comment: tst3 == 1; should be tst3 = 1;.

Comment: `{tst3 == 1;}` change all tst1,2,3 to `{tst3 = 1;}`

Comment: 1) `int tst1, tst2, tst3, tst4 = 0;` --> `int tst1=0, tst2=0, tst3=0, tst4 = 0;`

Comment: 2) `db_size++;` move to last. (also this doesn't update caller side `db_size`)

Comment: in last `while` condition you have to use `tst4 == 0` but you are using `tst3 == 0`

Comment: 3) You need to clear the input when there is an invalid input (ID).

Comment: Generally when taking user input, you will want to use a ***line-oriented*** input function (e.g. `fgets` or POSIX `getline`). Otherwise ***You*** are responsible for handling the `'\n'` that `scanf` will leave unread in the ***input buffer*** (e.g. `stdin`) just waiting to screw you over on your next call to `scanf`. If you are going to use `scanf`, then spend the time required in `man scanf` to study the *conversion specifiers* so that you understand how to properly account for the `'\n'` created when the user presses `[Enter]` at the end of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, there are a number of considerations involved when reading user input with `scanf`. That is why, as a general proposition, *line-oriented* is preferred (e.g. `fgets` or `getline`) which will eliminate the problems caused by leaving `'\n'` in the *input buffer* (`stdin` here). Both `fgets` and `getline` read up to *and including* the newline (generated when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard. After reading with either, you simply pass the string read to `sscanf` to parse the needed information from the string read.

That said, you can process input with `scanf`, but it is **Your** responsibility to handle the `'\n'`.

Before looking at `scanf`, let's talk about your function which you currently have as type `void`. That is a complete waste of the return which can be used to indicate success or failure of input. How will you handle the user canceling input (say with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (on Linux) or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> (windoze)) When taking input in a function, always provide a return value that can be used to indicate success/failure. Here you could simply return a pointer to the new node to indicate success, or `NULL` to indicate failure. Then your function would be of type `Employee *` instead of `void`.

That said, `scanf` with the `%s` format specifier reads *up to, but NOT including the first whitespace or* `'\n'`. So when you user enters `name` and presses enter, you capture `"name"` in your variable, but `'\n'` remains in `stdin`. If you next input is a numeric type, or type `char`, then `scanf` happily uses the `'\n'` as the value from the user (given the appearance that `scanf` has skipped a prompt). To prevent `scanf` from taking the `'\n'` a the next value, regardless of type, you can precede the *format specifier* with a `space` (e.g. `" %s"`) which will cause `scanf` to ignore all whitespace before the first non-whitespace character (a `'\n'` is considered whitespace).

You can also use the *assignment suppression operator* to `scanf`. (e.g. `"%s%*c"`) where the `'*'` before the `c` tells `scanf` to *read and discard* the next character (without affecting the *match count* returned by `scanf`). You can read about it in `man scanf`. (it also makes more sense when reading a maximum number of character that can include embedded whitespace, e.g. `" %99[^\n]%*c"` for a max `100 char` string -- including the `nul-byte`)

To read a string not containing whitespace with `scanf`, you can insure you receive input while also allowing the user to cancel input with a manual `EOF` without all your `tst1, tst2, ...` variables. Take for example the `temp_first` value. You can do something like:

```
    int return_val;  /* capture the return of scanf */
    ...
    printf ("\nPlease enter a first name: ");
    while ((return_val = scanf (" %s", temp_first)) != 1) {
        if (return_val == EOF)      /* trap manual EOF  */
            return NULL;            /* return NULL for error */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid first name.\n");
        printf ("Please enter a first name: ");
    }
```

This will accomplish what you attempted with all the additional `tst` values in a much more straightforward manner.

When you go to read `temp_six_digit_id`, it makes much more sense to take the input as a string. This makes determining that you indeed have `6` digits a simple call to `strlen`. Here you can do something similar to:

```
    printf ("Please enter the six digit ID number: ");
    while ((return_val = scanf (" %s", temp_id)) != 1 ||
            strlen (temp_id) != 6) {
        if (return_val == EOF)
            return NULL;
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid ID.\n");
        printf ("Please enter the six digit ID number: ");
    }
    temp_six_digit_id = (int)strtol (temp_id, NULL, 10);
    /* strtol validations omitted (see man strtod example) */
```

(you may as well read `salary` as a string as well and retain the error checking/handling `strtol` provides).

Below is a short example that puts all the pieces together in a way you can experiment with it outside your full code. You will have to adapt it to the rest of your code, but that should be relatively trivial.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* constants, max(employees, ID, salary, name) */
enum { MAXE = 3, MAXID = 32, MAXSAL = 64, MAXNAME = 256 };

typedef struct {
    char first_name[MAXNAME],
        last_name[MAXNAME];
    int six_digit_id,
        salary;
} Employee;

int main (void) {

    Employee db[MAXE] = {{ .first_name = "" }};
    char temp_first[MAXNAME] = "",
         temp_last[MAXNAME] = "",
         temp_id[MAXID] = "",
         temp_sal[MAXSAL] = "";
    int temp_six_digit_id = 0,
        temp_salary = 0,
        return_val = 0,
        db_size = 0;

    while (db_size < MAXE) {

        printf ("\nPlease enter a first name: ");
        while ((return_val = scanf (" %s", temp_first)) != 1) {
            if (return_val == EOF)      /* trap manual EOF  */
                return 1;           /* return NULL for error */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid first name.\n");
            printf ("Please enter a first name: ");
        }

        printf ("Please enter a last name: ");
        while ((return_val = scanf (" %s", temp_last)) != 1) {
            if (return_val == EOF)
                return 1;
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid last name.\n");
            printf ("Please enter a last name: ");
        }

        printf ("Please enter the six digit ID number: ");
        while ((return_val = scanf (" %s", temp_id)) != 1 ||
                strlen (temp_id) != 6) {
            if (return_val == EOF)
                return 1;
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid ID.\n");
            printf ("Please enter the six digit ID number: ");
        }
        temp_six_digit_id = (int)strtol (temp_id, NULL, 10);
        /* strtol validations omitted (see man strtod example) */

        printf ("Please enter the salary: ");
        while ((return_val = scanf (" %s", temp_sal)) != 1) {
            if (return_val == EOF)
                return 1;
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid salary.\n");
            printf ("Please enter a the salary: ");
        }
        temp_salary = (int)strtol (temp_sal, NULL, 10);

        strcpy(db[db_size].first_name, temp_first);
        strcpy(db[db_size].last_name, temp_last);
        db[db_size].six_digit_id = temp_six_digit_id;
        db[db_size].salary = temp_salary;

        db_size++;  /* 'db_size' is a copy here, changes are not visible in the
                     caller, pass a pointer to db_size to make change visible */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < db_size; i++)
        printf ("\n name   : %s %s\n ID     : %d\n salary : %d\n",
                db[i].first_name, db[i].last_name, db[i].six_digit_id,
                db[i].salary);

    return 0;
}
```

(pay particular attention to the comment regarding `db_size`. If you expect to have the changes to `db_size` visible back in the calling function, you will need to pass a pointer to `db_size` instead of `db_size` itself.)

**Example Use/Input**

```
$ ./bin/emp_input

Please enter a first name: Mary
Please enter a last name: Jane
Please enter the six digit ID number: 123
error: invalid ID.
Please enter the six digit ID number: 123456
Please enter the salary: 937

Please enter a first name: John
Please enter a last name: Doe
Please enter the six digit ID number: 234567
Please enter the salary: 1024

Please enter a first name: Bill
Please enter a last name: Jones
Please enter the six digit ID number: 234568
Please enter the salary: 1020

 name   : Mary Jane
 ID     : 123456
 salary : 937

 name   : John Doe
 ID     : 234567
 salary : 1024

 name   : Bill Jones
 ID     : 234568
 salary : 1020
```

*Note*: there are many ways to approach user input. This was chose to be as close to your original attempt as practical. If you have questions, or problems with further implementation, just let me know and I'll be happy to help further.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely amazing. Great break down of everything, I really appreciate it and now it makes sense. I wish there was a way to send a private message but the meeting of law and technology is something that I find fascinating.

Comment: Glad I could help. No matter what you are attempting to learn in life, you just have to keep at it until the proverbial light-bulb finally winks on. I can try to learn something 10 different ways and none make sense, until I find it explained in a way that just clicks. (subconsciously you have picked something up from the 10 prior failed attempts as well....) So keep at it, C is no different than any other topic, there are just a lot more rabbit-holes to follow. (which you would expect from a language that provides hardware-level control)

Answer (score 0):

Change `tst3==1` to `tst3=1`. Same for `tst1`,`tst2`.

The assignment operator (`=`) and the equality operator (`==`) appear to be similar but are used for completely different reasons.

The assignment operator (`=`) is used to assign a value to a [lvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue).

Whereas equality operator (`==`) is used to compare two values or expressions. The result is `1` if the equality is true and `0` if equality is false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use assignment Operator.

```
if(scanf("%s", temp_first) == 1){tst1 == 1;}
//change tst1 == 1; to tst1 = 1;

if(scanf("%s", temp_last) == 1){tst2 == 1;}
//change tst2 == 1; to tst2 = 1;

if(scanf("%d", &temp_six_digit_id) == 1){tst3 == 1;}
//change tst3 == 1; to tst3 = 1;
```

in last while condition you have to use variable `tst4` but you are using `tst3`

```
if(scanf("%d", &temp_salary) ==1){tst4 == 1;}  // use tst4 = 1
else{
        printf("Please enter a valid Salary:\n");
        while(tst3 == 0){  // you need to use tst4 == 0

        if(scanf("%d", &temp_salary) == 1){tst3 == 1;}  //use tst4 = 1;
        else{printf("Please enter a valid Salary:\n");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare values, you need to use `==` and to assign values `=`